Davis's lemma for countable prime avoidance
Let $R$ be a commutative ring. We say that a collection $\mathcal{P}$ of ideals of $R$ satisfies the avoidance property (AP) iff for any ideal $I \leq R$, $I \subseteq \bigcup_{J \in \mathcal{P}} J$ only if $I \subseteq J$ for some $J \in \mathcal{P}$. The prime avoidance lemma says that finite set of prime ideals has the AP (in fact, two of the ideals may be non-prime). By taking the contrapositive $\mathcal{P}$ satisfies the AP iff for every $I \leq R$, if $I \not\subseteq J$ for all $J \in \mathcal{P}$ then there is some $f \in I$ such that $f \notin J$ for all $J \in \mathcal{P}$. When $\mathcal{P} \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} R$ this contrapositive says every neighborhood $U = V(I)^c$ of $\mathcal{P}$ can be shrunk to a distinguished open $\mathcal{P} \subseteq D(f) \subseteq U$, i.e. distinguished opens are cofinal in the neighborhood filter of $\mathcal{P}$. This gives a topological interpretation of the prime avoidance lemma.
But there's another form of the prime avoidance lemma, which I will call "Davis prime avoidance", saying if a coset $x + I$ is contained in a finite union of primes $\mathfrak{p}_1 \cup \cdots \cup \mathfrak{p}_n$ then $x + I \subseteq \mathfrak{p}_i$ for some $i$. One can get this from prime avoidance with the lemma that $x + I \subseteq \mathfrak{p}_1 \cup \cdots \cup \mathfrak{p}_n$ implies $(x) + I \subseteq \mathfrak{p}_1 \cup \cdots \cup \mathfrak{p}_n$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3311653/408287, and I prefer to think of it as a  corollary of the standard prime avoidance lemma because the latter admits a topological pov. The argument I know for this lemma uses that there are finitely many primes not just in its application of prime avoidance but also when it says some $\mathfrak{p}_i$ contains an intersection of other $\mathfrak{p}_j$ and thus (by primality) we must have $\mathfrak{p}_i \supseteq \mathfrak{p}_j$ for some $j$. (Edit: we also need finiteness to ensure there are no containments among the primes, but without it we can still ensure that there are no containments of a prime not containing $x$ within a prime containing $x$, which is good enough.)
There are other places where the avoidance property holds for a set of primes, notably if $R$ is complete, Noetherian, local then any countable $\mathcal{P} \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} R$ has the AP. And the way this is proved (by the Baire category theorem for the adic topology) generalizes immediately to prove "countable Davis prime avoidance". But the reduction breaks down, because a prime ideal can contain an infinite intersection without containing any members (e.g. the Krull intersection theorem gives plenty of examples).
Is there a reduction from countable Davis prime avoidance to countable prime avoidance for complete Noetherian local rings? In general, if the AP holds for $\mathcal{P}$ (maybe assumed a set of prime ideals) does the "Davis-AP" hold for $\mathcal{P}$? Or, alternatively, is there a topological interpretation of the Davis-AP?
